# How can I login to IMAP using SASL

Tags: perl, imap, sasl

I'm am coding an email app and I need to acccess gmail through SASL

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

I am able to construct the SASL url and login using [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mail-IMAPClient/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod), but my whole backend is using [`Net::IMAP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Simple) how can I login throug SASL with `Net::IMAP::Simple`